# New Custom centos boot disk with parameters from official google cloud setting

Tags: linux, cloud, boot, disk, google-compute-engine

**I want to change the root filesystem CentOs 6 to Btrfs filesystem.**

My solution is to export virtual machine from localhost to GCE, I know the documentation to this job, but I have doubts how does work the process the import of boot disk images  (You can import boot disk images from your physical datacenters, from virtual machines on your local workstation, or from virtual machines that run on another cloud platform. )

My question is relation to documenation of https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images:

Notable differences from standard CentOS images

Google Compute Engine-provided CentOS images contain the following differences from standard CentOS images:

- All packages are updated to the date of the image and the image will reflect the latest CentOS point release.
- Google Cloud repositories are enabled to install packages from the Linux Guest Environment for Google Compute Engine.
- Google CloudSDK is installed.
- IPv6 is disabled as it is not yet supported on Compute Engine.
- The eth0 MTU is set to 1460.
- DHCP is set to retry every 10 seconds instead of 5 minutes.
- The DHCP client is set to persistent mode instead of oneshot.
  ......
  ......
  ......

So my question is, **¿when I imported a boot disk CentOs from my computer to GCE, does GCE apply all this parameters to my boot disk CentOs, so To be compatible with the standard settings of google image CentOs?**

If this does not, then:
**¿How can i proceed?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the solution:

There is a free service that helps with VM migrations but is limited to some OS.  CentOS 6.0 is included but I am not sure if it supports the file system you are looking for.

If you cannot use the migration service and you do not  want to use the public images provided by Google, then you must take care of the bootloader and all OS configuration you mentioned.  You might also want to have a look to this link, in public Google images some daemons are installed by default. They add GCE functionality like syncing the accounts used in your project with the VMs.